# What happens when assumptions about the distribution of the latent variable in a GLMM are violated?

Tags: mixed-model, glmm, assumptions, latent-variable

I am struggling with one assumption usually made when using linear mixed models: the nature of the distribution of the random factor. (The first part of the question is more about biology --whether the assumption is justified-- but the second part is more about the consequences for the model if they are not.)

Often we have the case that we have a variable with a few levels (e.g. 2 years, 3 field sites, 4 batches, etc..) The question whether or not to treat such a variable as fixed or random has been discussed repeatedly. The first argument usually brought up is a conceptual one: the decision should be based on whether I am only specifically interested in those levels or whether I see these levels/sites/batches as a random sample of a large number of possible levels/sites/batches. I agree with this. Another line of reasoning focuses more on the technical aspects, with some people arguing that with very few levels it will be hard to make good estimates of the variance of the random factor (and rules of thumb suggest between 5 and 15 levels at least), while others (e.g Gelman & Hill) argue that even 2 or 1 levels are in principle o.k. –you may not gain anything in such a case, but  you are also not losing anything either because “with only one or two groups multilevel modeling just reduces to classical regression”. I also accept this argument. However, here is now my question: if I have only a few levels (say below 10) I will not only have a hard time estimating the variance of the random factor accurately, but it will also be difficult (or impossible) to see what kind of underlying distribution this random factor has. As far as I have seen (but please correct me if I am wrong) in most cases people assume a neat Gaussian distribution for the random factor. It seems that this might sometimes/often be done out of convenience. (This is the default assumption of all mixed model packages I have heard of, and usually you cannot even opt for a different distribution for the random factor.) Now, I want to challenge this assumption and ask: (A) is there any good empirical support indicating that those kind of random factors that we encounter frequently in biology are usually normally distributed (this part of the question is more about biology and less about statistics, so it might not be discussed here) and (B) what happens if they are not but we treat them as such?

I recently read the following quote (attributed to Whittaker and Robinson): “Everybody believes in the exponential law of errors [i.e., the Normal distribution]: the experimenters, because they think it can be proved by mathematics; and the mathematicians, because they believe it has been established by observation.” Now, my suspicion is that this might also be the case when it comes to the distribution of random factors in biological models (and I will bring an example below that –at least in my case—this might not work). Which leads me directly to my question B: what kind of consequences can it have if my assumption (a normal distribution for the random variable) is violated, because in reality I have a highly skewed or even bimodal or otherwise oddly shaped distribution?

Here is my example: It is about the effect of a specific treatment of stroke in lab mice. The design is simple with just a treatment and a control group and a few mice in each group. The same experiment was done in several laboratories. Laboratories differ slightly in several aspects and we might have more variation between laboratories than within, which suggests analysing the data together having treatment as a fixed effect and laboratory as random effect. This is the ‘standard’ way how such multi-lab studies are analysed. Now, in my case, I do not have just three or four or five labs but 50. This is a really large number for a multi-lab study. And with such a large number of levels for the random factor it should be possible not only to assume an underlying distribution for the random factor, but to look at it by plotting a histogram of the lab mean values. The resulting histogram doesn't look like a normal distribution at all. (In fact, a uniform distribution gives a better fit.)

[image: Distribution of 50 mean estimates from 50 independent studies]

So, the ‘standard mixed model’ that I might have made would be questionable because one underlying assumption of this model is most likely violated. Now, if the assumption is violated here, it might be violated in many other cases as well. We might never know, because most multi-lab studies combine data from 2 to usually less than 10 labs or centres and with such a small number of values you can’t properly deduce the underlying distribution. Maybe you can prove me wrong and there is convincing evidence that in most cases in biomedical research or any area where mixed models are frequently used, it has been established beyond doubt that most often the assumption of normal distribution for the random factor is justified. Otherwise I would love to learn how much a violation of this assumption matters and when it can have detrimental effects on the results.

Many thanks for any comments!

Comment: +1 Excellent question, which I've been wrestling with as well. I've seen some suggestions that 30-100 levels are necessary, and my guess would be that if you have, say, 80 levels a normal distribution might work well enough in almost all cases. I love the R package `brms`, which lets you vary a lot of things but even it doesn't allow you to modify the RE distribution.